# Node.js won't install on Windows 7 x64

Tags: node.js, windows

I tried the following methods all of which have failed

1. Running the .msi installer via the GUI from the Node site (no option given for running as admin)
2. Running the .msi installer via comandline as admin
3. Running choclatey installer as admin

Here is the choclatey output as seen in the log

```
Downloading nodejs.install 64 bit
   from 'https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.10.1/node-v5.10.1-x64.msi'
 Installing nodejs.install...
 [ERROR] Running msiexec with /i "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\nodejs.install\5.10.1\nodejs.installInstall.msi" /quiet  was not successful. Exit code was '1603' Error Mess

 age:
 .
 At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions\Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin.ps1:92 char:10
 +     throw <<<<  $errorMessage
     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: ([ERROR] Running...or Message:
 .:String) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [ERROR] Running msiexec with /i "C:\Users\tcastonzo\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\nodejs.install\5.10.1\nodejs.installInstall.msi" /quiet  was not successful.

    Exit code was '1603' Error Message:
 .
The install of nodejs.install was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 package(s). 1 package(s) failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Failures:
 - nodejs.install
PS C:\GitProjects\reporting> choco install nodejs.install
Installing the following packages:
nodejs.install
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Win-7 with node-v6.10.3-x64.msi and node-v6.10.3-x86.msi installers.

**Solution:**

Download the Zipped version; When extracting, note the file that causes error.
Then, using Explorer, drill down to the target folder, created an empty file, then copy the content of archived file into the new, empty file.

I think the FQ path to destination is too long. Following is the error message I received.

```
!   C:\Users\......\Downloads\node-v6.10.3-win-x64.zip: Cannot create node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\string-width\node_modules\is-fullwidth-code-point\node_modules\number-is-nan\package.json

!   The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting the message, @BSMP. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since support for windows 7 ended for Nodejs .I found the manual installment easier.
see this comment from github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33000#issuecomment-644530517

Do follow the same steps with the binary zip file from : [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Answer (score -1):

I the exact same error in Windows 10.

After launched my shell, making sure I was running as administrator, it worked.